# Problem running Spyder 4.0.0+ on a New Environments on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Windows 10 - 64x.

I am new to Python as well as to Anaconda. I downloaded what I believe is the latest version of Anaconda from the official webpage, and I wanted to create a new environment for a new project for which I need Spyder.

Every time I try to launch Spyder, the program doesn't respond and I get the following error:
`[16748:16200:0331/091204.775:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)[3424:6876:0331/091204.775:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)`

Please note that in the "base" environment i managed to make Spyder work just using the command:
`conda update anaconda`
after which version 4.0.1 of Spyder is running smoothly. Still, I cannot make the same version working on any other new environment I create. Neither the following Spyder versions work.

Please help!